# ! Undefined control sequence \backsim

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

My `latex` file does not accept the command  `\backsim`. This is what I wrote in the file:

```
$ \backsim 2.5 \mu$
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you loading `amssymb` package? `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Comment: do you mean I need to get a package?. Lately, i loaded some packages from CTAN which seemed to be missing. Why I need to load every time?. I might have other errors and need to load more packages and my file will be full of stuff!!!

Comment: @Naema It means you should call it inside your file: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$ \backsim 2.5 \mu$
\end{document}

Comment: Just insert `\usepackage{amssymb}` on preamble (before `\begin{document}`). If you already have some AMS packages you can use comma and insert `amssymb` together. Usually I always load `\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}`.

Comment: oh, I did and it solved my problem. I put \usepackage{amssymb}.thanks

Comment: @Naema: Next time you get such an error for a symbol, you can [search the symbol on my page](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/stats/), [click on it](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/symbol/?id=630) and take a look at "package" and "mode".

Comment: @Naema: Just out of curiosity: Why do you need backsim?

Comment: moose, I needed to use the mathematical symbol for approximation. I wanted to mention that a value is almost equal to 2.5um but not exactly equal.

Comment: @Naema - installing a package only makes it available. You have to specify in the document that you actually want to use it. Packages can change the way LaTeX works, so LaTeX doesn't make any assumptions about what packages you want -- you have to tell it explicitly. (Imagine trying to figure out what's going on if it didn't work that way!)

Comment: yes Tom,thanks, now I understand how to fix such errors.I already put this:\usepackage{amssymb} at the begining ,  and my problem was solved.